# Why isn't cognitive psychology part of a math undergrad/grad program?

Tags: soft-question

I think it is good for math students to have a cognitive psychology course. Foreign languages are often required. If a student knows how his mind works he would use it more efficiently. Insight, for example, occurs after a burst of gamma waves followed by alpha waves. In layman terms this means that a person stuck on a math problem usually gets an aha moment when he is relaxing. Opinions?

**Edit.** For example, I see many students now live-TeXing notes. That is a very inefficient way of learning.

Comment: This is certainly not a math question. I would close this as off-topic.

Comment: Plenty of mathematicians are quite successful without any self-awareness at all. Clearly not a requirement for the job. :)

Comment: In the same vein one could ask why there are usually no courses on making good coffee or indian food...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: But they would do better if they were are of it.

Comment: Sorry, but I see no evidence of that. That's purely assertion. Quite a few of the most highly functioning adults are people who have no understanding of congnition. Can you give us any study that indicates that studying cognition improves their functioning?

Comment: Everyone should learn about cognitive psychology, but this doesn't make it on-topic. Your claim about gamma and alpha waves is not very convincing.

Comment: Note, you are also not really intending this as a question, but rather making a suggesting and attempting to start a debate. That is not the intent of this site.

Comment: I think the opposite is more relevant: why so many [not just cognitive] psychologists can't handle anything more sophisticated than a TV program

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not mathematics...

Answer (score 1):

Cognitive science is not of benefit only or mostly to mathematics, nor is it so critical that one cannot do without it.  Therefore, it might be a general knowledge requirement, but would not be appropriate for a requirement for math.